# Possessed dwarf won't collect bones

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In dwarf fortress (latest version 27/03/2019) all the possessed dwarfs that I have had have failed to collect the bones that they require and instead go insane. I'm new to dwarf fortress.

I have tried looking online but other peoples who's issues were usually fixed haven't worked for me.
I have also tried deleting the refuse stockpile (outside but close enough to my craft shop (the shop that my dwarf claimed)), moving it closer, butchering new animals, and letting my butcher get clogged up. I honestly have no idea. My assumption is that either I've toggled something in the game that I shouldn't have or this is a bug. Thanks.

Comment: Does this problem only happen with bones? Can your possessed dwarves collect other kinds of items?

Comment: @Wrigglenite So far I've only had issues with bones. Is it perhaps that I require the bones of a certain type of animal?

Comment: It doesn't require bones from any specific animal. Does the dwarf have a valid path to the refuse pile or butcher shop? Are the bones forbidden? Is the dwarf assigned to a burrow that doesn't have access? Dwarves will always collect the items they need in the exact order they say, so I'm wondering if they're getting stuck on a different item before they go to get the bones.

Comment: @Paul I didn't that their collected in an order.  How do I tell which is the first item? Hes cycling through wood, leather, and bone.

Comment: @Reflexive it can be tough to tell which is the first one. If you hit T you can inspect the contents of the building he claimed. The materials he has already gathered will be there and they're marked as TSK (task) I think. If it says he has dog hide, then whatever he says after leather is what he is waiting for. Sometimes what he asks for repeats. For example if he needed 2 rocks and wood, he would say ROCKS, ROCKS, WOOD. It would just look like he asked for rocks once (but the message would be up for twice as long) so you might need to make sure there's multiple available leather and wood too

Comment: @Paul Ok Ill see if this was the cause (the next time i get a possessed dwarf, the last one went loco).